# how to rollback tran when error occur in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**i try to solve 2 requests below but i only code for the first one,,
can any one help to solve the second one**

1. Write SQL statements using cursor to update salary of all employees base on update
   conditionals
2. Make sure all update records have been updated completely. The database
   transaction will be rolled back if any update failure).

```
declare
cur_empno int;
cursor salary_increment  IS
select employee.empno from EMPLOYEE 
where emplevel in(
    select EmpNo from EMP_SKILL
    group by EmpNo
    having count(*)>1
);
begin
open salary_increment;
loop
fetch salary_increment into cur_empno;
exit when salary_increment%notfound;
update EMPLOYEE set Salary=Salary+300000 
where EmpNo=cur_empno and empLevel=2 and add_months(startdate,24)<=current_date;
update EMPLOYEE set Salary=Salary+500000 
where EmpNo=cur_empno and empLevel=3 and add_months(startdate,36)<=current_date;
end loop;
close salary_increment;
end;
```

Comment: I think it will already roll back on failure. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
declare
cur_empno int;
cursor salary_increment  IS
select employee.empno from EMPLOYEE 
where emplevel in(
    select EmpNo from EMP_SKILL
    group by EmpNo
    having count(*)>1
);
begin
open salary_increment;
loop
fetch salary_increment into cur_empno;
exit when salary_increment%notfound;
update EMPLOYEE set Salary=Salary+300000 
where EmpNo=cur_empno and empLevel=2 and add_months(startdate,24)<=current_date;
update EMPLOYEE set Salary=Salary+500000 
where EmpNo=cur_empno and empLevel=3 and add_months(startdate,36)<=current_date;
end loop;
close salary_increment;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;

COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: thank you. but what is "OTHERS" and "ABC" in EXCEPTION.

Comment: when others will trap all the un mentioned exception. in this case all exception. to ABC was to rollback to a save point ABC. In this case you don’t need this. I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> how to rollback tran[saction] when error occur in oracle

Do not use `COMMIT` or any DDL statements and the transaction will automatically rollback if there is an exception.

If you `COMMIT` then the transaction can only rollback to the `COMMIT` (rather than to the beginning of the transaction). If you use a DDL statement then it will issue an implicit `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

You have few problems with your code. I think you should try below code -

```
DECALRE
cur_empno int;
cursor salary_increment  IS
select employee.empno
  from EMPLOYEE 
 where emplevel in(select EmpNo from EMP_SKILL        -- Column name should be Emplevel instead of Empno.
                    group by EmpNo
                   having count(*)>1);
BEGIN
     OPEN salary_increment;
     LOOP
         FETCH salary_increment INTO cur_empno;
         EXIT WHEN salary_increment%notfound;
         
         -- Use Single Update column instead of multiple update statement.
         update EMPLOYEE
            set Salary= CASE WHEN empLevel=2 AND add_months(startdate,24)<=current_date 
                                  THEN Salary + 300000 
                             WHEN empLevel=3 AND add_months(startdate,36)<=current_date
                                  THEN Salary + 500000
          where EmpNo=cur_empno
            and empLevel IN (2, 3)
            and add_months(startdate,36)<=current_date;

     END LOOP;
     CLOSE salary_increment;
     -- Use 1 commit at the end of transaction.
     COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    -- Rollback the transaction if there is any issue.
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;

END;
```